# Building blogdown site twice leads to incorrect formatting

Tags: r, blogdown

Rebuilding blogdown site is not rendering correctly for some themes.

Having created a new directory using the R Project Wizard in RStudio, I create a new site using a custom theme such as "AlexFinn/simple-a" or "zwbetz-gh/vanilla-bootstrap-hugo-theme" with `blogdown::new_site(theme = "AlexFinn/simple-a")`. Once created, I add the following to to `config.TOML`; `ignoreFiles = ["\\.Rmd$", "\\.Rmarkdown$", "_files$", "_cache$"]`

At this point, all is working as expected and I get a properly formatted example site.

When I press the 'Build Website' button in the Build panel in RStudio again OR I upload to Netlify, for these two themes, my website is rendered with all styling and images removed; black text - bolded and sized - and with a plain white background. With "gcushen/hugo-academic" the colours appear but the images are missing. Nothing appears different with the "road2stat/hugo-tanka".

I would understand this behaviour with the vanilla theme but "simple-a" and "hugo-academic" are mentioned in the blogdown book in chapter 1.6

I am using Hugo 0.53 and blogdown_0.10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Build Website` is not for rendering the blogdown website, What it does is to render multiple Rmarkdown documents into a website.

You should use `Addins -> Serve Site` or call the command `blogdown::serve_site()` instead.

For more information on the difference between `rmarkdown::render_site()` and blogdown, you can read

- `help("render_site", package="rmarkdown")` and
- [The rmarkdown official manual](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-13.html)